# How to deploy Mercure Binary on heroku?

Tags: heroku, mercure

I am trying to deploy my Mercure server on a Heroku app
I downloaded a Linux version of Mercure and extract it and I added this `procfile` to it:

```
web: ADDR=$PORT ./mercure
```

and I pushed everything using Heroku git

```
git push heroku master
```

but it doesn't work and Mercure fails in the building.
I can't find any tutorial or anything inside the documentation.

How can I deploy my Mercure binary on Heroku?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

In order to deploy Mercure binary on Heroku, you need to use a **Binary Buildpack**.

I suggest this one: https://github.com/ph3nx/heroku-binary-buildpack

After creating a new app on Heroku, you can set that buildpack using **`buildpacks:set`**

Run this command:

```
heroku buildpacks:set https://github.com/ph3nx/heroku-binary-buildpack -a myapp
```

Add a procfile to your Mercure folder, it should contain:

```
web: ./mercure -k "$SECRET" -c '*' -p '*' -a :$PORT -D -X
```

and then push everything to Heroku.